# What happened to TFS knowing that "The files are identical"?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013, and I’ve noticed the Pending-Changes screen no longer informs me that “The files are identical” when appropriate.

I often have a list of files displayed in my Pending-Changes screen.  Some of those files have been unnecessarily checked-out by me, so I try to clean-up my list daily.  In Visual Studio 2010, I can right-click on a file in Pending Changes, and click Compare > With Latest Version.  When my local version matches the Latest Version, I get a notification saying, “The files are identical”.

However, in VS2013, when I compare a local file w/ Latest, the file-comparison window opens and displays two identical files side-by-side with no changes highlighted (because there ARE no changes to highlight).  Is this an option/feature I can change in VS2013?

Comment: Have you tried the `Undo Unchanged` button in the Source Control Explorer to simply remove the unchanged files? It's added by this extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/af70cbb7-1e0d-4d16-bc57-cccc15370c51

Answer (score 0):

It's a change in behavior in VS 2013. I'd suggest entering it on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com).

Comment: This behavior persists in VS 2015 :-(